# data type mismatch in FtpFindFirstFile

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, wininet

I am enumerating an ftp directory using the following function:

```
Public Sub EnumFiles(hConnect As Long)
Const cstrProcedure = "EnumFiles"
Dim pData As WIN32_FIND_DATA, hFind As Long, lRet As Long
Dim strSubCode As String
Dim sql As String
On Error GoTo HandleError

sql = "INSERT INTO tblIncomingFiles (AvailableFile) Values ('" & pData.cFileName & "')"
'get sub code to search with
strSubCode = GetSubscriberCode
'create a buffer
pData.cFileName = String(MAX_PATH, 0)
'find the first file
hFind = FtpFindFirstFile(hConnect, "*" & strSubCode & "*", pData, 0, 0)
'if there's no file, then exit sub
If hFind = 0 Then Exit Sub
'show the filename
Debug.Print Left(pData.cFileName, InStr(1, pData.cFileName, String(1, 0), vbBinaryCompare) - 1)
CurrentDb.Execute sql
Do
    'create a buffer
    pData.cFileName = String(MAX_PATH, 0)
    'find the next file
    'lRet = FtpFindNextFile(hFind, pData.cFileName)
    'if there's no next file, exit do
    If lRet = 0 Then Exit Do
    'show the filename
    'Me.Print Left(pData.cFileName, InStr(1, pData.cFileName, String(1, 0), vbBinaryCompare) - 1)
    CurrentDb.Execute sql
Loop
'close the search handle


HandleExit:

    Exit Sub

HandleError:
    ErrorHandle Err, Erl(), cstrModule & "." & cstrProcedure
    Resume HandleExit
End Sub
```

I keep getting a Data type mismatch (Error 13) in this line:

```
hFind = FtpFindFirstFile(hConnect, "*" & strSubCode & "*", pData, 0, 0)
```

and it highlights pData.
I have declared pData as WIN32_FIND_DATA at the top of the function, and WIN32_FIND_DATA is declared as a type in this module.

```
Public Declare Function FtpFindFirstFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpFindFirstFileA" _
(ByVal hFtpSession As Long, ByVal sSearchFile As String, ByVal lpFindFileData As Long,   _
ByVal lFlags As Long, ByVal dwContext As Long) As Long

Private Type WIN32_FIND_DATA
dwFileAttributes As Long
ftCreationTime As FILETIME
ftLastAccessTime As FILETIME
ftLastWriteTime As FILETIME
nFileSizeHigh As Long
nFileSizeLow As Long
dwReserved0 As Long
dwReserved1 As Long
cFileName As String * MAX_PATH
cAlternate As String * 14
End Type
```

Any idea why I might be getting that error?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the `Type` declaration for `WIN32_FIND_DATA` in that module, and the complete `Declare Function FtpFindFirstFile` line as well.

Comment: @GordThompson I added the requested code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working example that I found [here](http://www.ex-designz.net/apidetail.asp?api_id=416), and my `FtpFindFirstFile` declaration is slightly different from yours. Mine is

```
Private Declare Function FtpFindFirstFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpFindFirstFileA" _
(ByVal hFtpSession As Long, ByVal lpszSearchFile As String, lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA, _
ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwContent As Long) As Long
```